# PHP ZipArchive fails to extract CSV files properly

Tags: php, zip, extract, php-ziparchive

A real head scratcher this one - any help would be gratefully received.

I have been using the zipArchive library to extract csv files from a zip.

Oddly, it will only extract 40 files properly.  Files with an index 40 or greater appear as empty files, files 0-39 extract perfectly.

This is the case regardless of the combination of files and the size of the files.  I have tried removing the 39th file and the 40th file from the zip and the problem just moves.  No matter what combination of files I use, it extracts 40 files properly and then just dies.

Thanks to this forum, I have tried using Shell Exec with exactly the same outcome.
I have also tried extracting the files one at a time, using a zip with only the csv files and zips with multiple different file types.  Always only 40 are extracted.

This is such a suspiciously round number that it must surely be a setting somewhere that I cannot find or otherwise a bug.

For what it is worth, the unzipping code is below:

```
    $zip = new ZipArchive;
    if ($zip->open('Directory/zipname.zip') == TRUE) {
     for ($i = 0; $i < $zip->numFiles; $i++) {
        $filename = $zip->getNameIndex($i);
         if(substr(strrchr($filename,'.'),1,3)=="csv")
        {
         $zip->extractTo('Directory/',$filename);
        }
        }
    }
```

I have also tried the following which uses a different method with the same results :-(

```
$zip2 = new ZipArchive;
if ($zip2->open('Directory/zipname.zip') == TRUE) {
 for ($i = 0; $i < $zip2->numFiles; $i++) {
     $filename = $zip2->getNameIndex($i);
     if(substr(strrchr($filename,'.'),1,3)=="csv")
            {
            $content=$zip2->getFromIndex($i);
            $thefile=fopen("directory/filename","w");
            fwrite($thefile,$content);
            fclose($thefile);
            }


 }
}
```

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: Also, if it is PHP related issue, an alternative method that may work is using `exec()` to use the systems native ZIP binary. The only issue with that, is that there may not be a ZIP handler on the server. Just a thought.

Comment: Just to be sure - did you try to extract files by other archiver, and does it work fine?

Comment: Thanks - already treid the exec method and the same problem occurs. PHP Version is 5.2.17  Apache 2.2.23.  If the exec() feature also produces the same result, would that suggest it is NOT PHP then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FINALLY found the answer.  Thanks to all who tried to help.

For others suffering in the same way, the problem was solved by increasing the server disk allocation.  I was on a rather old plan which had served well until the advent of a new national database that increased the amount of storage 10 fold.
A measly 100MB allowance meant that the server would only do so much before spitting the dummy.

Interestingly, a similar problem occurred with trying other file operations - it seemed to be limited to 40 file operations per script, regardless of the size of each file.